# MySQL Update Multiple Columns Issue

Tags: php, mysql

This seems to be a really simple query, but somehow I keep getting errors...

Basically, I just got a bunch of information from a user, and now I'm going to update their record in the `users` table in one query:

UPDATE `users` SET `timezone` = 'America/New_York', SET `updates` = 'NO', SET `verified` = 'YES' WHERE `id` = '1'

However, after running that, I get the following error:
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET `updates` = 'NO', SET `verified` = 'YES' WHERE `id` = '1'' at line 1".

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Like Yoda says, remove the extra "SET" bits. The syntax is `UPDATE ... SET field=value, field=value, field=value`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
UPDATE users SET timezone = 'America/New_York', updates = 'NO', verified = 'YES' WHERE id = '1'
```

Answer (score 4):

Your update syntax is wrong, you have to write syntax SET just once.

```
UPDATE users SET col1= value1, col2= value2, col3= value3 WHERE condition;
```

More information about update
[UPDATE MANUAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

Answer (score 0):

Set have to be used once no matter how many columns you are updating .your query will be :-

UPDATE users SET timezone = 'America/New_York', updates = 'NO',verified = 'YES' WHERE id = '1'